# Pass an unsigned short pointer to a function that as reference for cropping an image

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory

This program is crashing!, as a newbie can anyone say where is the memory getting corrupted here and what to do to fix this issue?

Here I am trying to extract an ROI from part of data and assigning it to original data back again.

Modified code below, here there is no issue and the 'newdata' will have cropped data from the original variable 'data'

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ExtractROI(unsigned short *image, int nRows, int nCols, unsigned short *imageROI)
{
    int indexROI = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
        {
            imageROI[indexROI] = image[i * nCols + j];
            indexROI++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int nRows = 12;
    const int nCols = 12;
    unsigned short *data = new unsigned short[nRows * nCols];
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
        {
            data[i * nCols + j] = i * nCols + j;
        }
    }

    unsigned short *newdata = new unsigned short[2 * 2];
    memset(newdata, 0, sizeof(unsigned short) * 2 * 2);

    ExtractROI(data, 2, 2, newdata);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << "(" << i << "," << j << ")" << " = " << newdata[i * 2 + j] << endl;
        }
    }

    delete[] data;
    delete[] newdata;

    char x;
    cin >> x;

    return 0;
}
```

/* Old code below*/

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ExtractROI(unsigned short *image, int nRows, int nCols, unsigned short *imageROI)
{
    int indexROI = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
        {
            imageROI[indexROI] = image[i * nCols + j];
            indexROI++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int nRows = 12;
    const int nCols = 12;
    unsigned short *data = new unsigned short[nRows * nCols];
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
        {
            data[i * nCols + j] = i * nCols + j;
        }
    }

    unsigned short *newdata = new unsigned short[2 * 2];
    memset(newdata, 0, sizeof(unsigned short) * 2 * 2);

    ExtractROI(data, nRows, nCols, newdata);

    data = newdata;

    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
        {
            cout << "(" << i << "," << j << ")" << " = " << data[i * nCols + j] << endl;
        }
    }

    /*delete[] data;
    delete[] newdata;*/

    char x;
    cin >> x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, use `std::vector`. Then, enable the diagnostic mode of your standard library. It will then tell you where you ran out of bounds. BTW: "crashing" is not an error description. Also, run the program in a debugger to get a backtrace and more of a clue where it fails. Lastly, research what "magic numbers" are.

Comment: you're not extracting ROI, you're just basically copying. you may be thinking of a `2x2` kernel to detect edges. but this isn't the way to do it. a kernel is not the storage for the "output".

Comment: I will edit the code now and this properly crops to 2x2 matrix.. please have a look

Comment: so what's the problem now?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loops in `ExtractROI` the variable `indexROI` will be increased a total of `nRows * nCols` times. Since you pass `12` for each, `indexROI` will at the end be `12 * 12` (or `144`). This is quite a lot more than the `2 * 2` (or `4`) elements allocated for `imageROI`.

Going out of bounds of allocated memory leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

After the call to `ExtractROI` you have the same problem in the loops there. As well as a memory leak (you lose what `data` is originally pointing to).

Comment: 'data' now will point to 2x2 array, how to make to point properly without loss of data?